# Translate database content using __($message) function

Tags: plugins, plugin-wpml

I've written a plugin that allows users to add information in the database. It runs well but I can't translate the information using WPML.
This is a simple example of the problem:

$message = 'test'; // here I get the information of the DB 
__($message, 'my-plugin');

Is there a way to workaround this problem? I don't know if we can use a variable instead of a string to translate. When I analize the widget in the Admin panel it don't show the string to translate.

This example works in WPML because is a string: __('test', 'my-plugin');

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `__()'` and `_e();` functions works with placeholders just fine and its a php functions and not a WPML functions, so either i'm not getting the question or it's just poorly stated, can you explain a bit more, what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Bainternet thanks for your answer, I'm trying to get information from the database and display with the translate functions `__()` and `_e()` , but instead of echoing a string like `_e('message','myplugin');` I want to echo the information I get from the DB , so I have a variable with the content I get like `_e($message,'myplugin'). This works well, echoing the information, but when I go to the WPML to translate the string it doesn't appear and I can't translate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have variables in your text to be translated the usual way would be with string formatting like so:

```
<?php
printf(__("text %s text2."), $message);
?>
```

with integers:

```
<?php
printf(__("text %d text2."), $count);
?>
```

with more then one placeholders:

```
<?php
printf(__("text %1$s text2 %2$S."), $message, $message2);
?>
```

but the variable it self will not be translated in no way.

WPML doesn't run the code before `__();` or `_e();` function it only search the files for them, and that is why when you write something like this:

```
$message = 'test'; // here I get the information of the DB
__($message, 'my-plugin');
```

WPML only sees `__($message, 'my-plugin');` where $message is empty.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought this could happen so now I have to change my code using other ways to display the information, maybe using custom post types.